# Missing Outlook 2007 Datafile?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, data-recovery, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using Outlook 2007 on Windows XP SP3.

I am having a problem with my Outlook datafile: Its completely disapeared!

Last night I used Outlook, everything ok, this morning I used Outlook again, everything OK, then I started a Full System Virus scan (Kaspersky Internet Security 2010) whcih ran for 4 hours before I went again into Outlook (scan had not yet finished) when Outlook popped up a message telling me that "The file C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.pst cannot be found".

I started a full system search (including system and hidden files/folders), which turned up nothing. I went to the C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\ folder and checked: nothing there. I checked the Scan log, it showed no record of a file being a deleted.

I then tried **6 File Recovery Programs** all of which turned up nothing.

I tried some of these Outlook Datafile Recovery Programs whcih turned up nothing.

Typically, I had not bothered to backup the Datafile since April.

I am at my wits end.

Does anyone know how I can recover the Datafile?

Comment: Have you searched for all PST files on your hard drive, making sure that Hidden and System files are included?

Comment: Yes, I say so in my question.

Comment: Have you looked at your Anti virus's folder ? It could be in a different name

Comment: No, there is nothing. There is not even a entry in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answer and comments!

I sent the machine into a PC Repair shop and 1 day later, they had recovered the data!

Something (maybe Kaspersky, they don't know) DID delete the PST file and the shop user what they call "Trade-Secrets" to get the file back.

Will back up reguarly now!

Answer (score 0):

If your antivirus was parametered to isolate infected files, I would look in its file vault.

If not, you might also try some file recovery product such as [PC INSPECTOR File Recovery](http://pcinspector.de/Sites/file%5Frecovery/ueber%5Funs.htm?language=1) or [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).

**EDIT**
Some more free file-recovery tools can be found here :
[Free Data, Hard Drive, Disk, Deleted File Recovery Software Programs Reviews](http://www.isoftwarereviews.com/free-data-hard-drive-disk-deleted-file-recovery-software-programs-reviews/)

Comment: As I said above, there is nothing in vault. I tried Recuva (in both normal and deep scan modes). I will try PC INSPECTOR File Recovery, though.

Comment: Tried PC INSPECTOR File Recovery, but it only allows the recovery of certain file types. This does not include .pst files.

Comment: Tried EVERY ONE OF THOSE PROGRAMS AND NOTHING! Wish I had made more backups...

Comment: It seems like Kaspersky did a very good job of erasing Outlook.pst, or you've overwritten it. Antivirus scans should always be parametered to work only on infectable files (exe, dll etc.), or they do weird things.

Comment: But thats the funny thing, Kaspersky is confirgued using the default settings which specifies that it ignores .pst files.

Comment: Losing your mail is never funny, but I'm afraid I can't help you in that.